# Format csv file with column creation in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file, as below

It has 6 rows with top row as header, while header read as "Students Marks"
dataframe is treating them as one columns, now i want to separate both columns with data. "student" and "marks" are separated by space.

```
df.show()    
_______________
##Student Marks##    
---------------    
A   10;20;10;20    
A   20;20;30;10    
B   10;10;10;10    
B   20;20;20;10    
B   30;30;30;20
```

Now i want to transform this csv table into two columns, with student and Marks, Also for every student the marks with add up, something like below

```
Student | Marks
A       | 30;40;40;30
B       | 60;60;60;40
```

I have tried with below but it is throwing an error

```
df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"Students Marks","\\ ")).select($"_tmp".getItem(0).as("col1"),$"_tmp".getItem(1).as("col2")).drop("_tmp")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the csv file with the delimiteryou want and calculate result as below

```
    val df = spark.read
      .option("header", true)
      .option("delimiter", " ")
      .csv("path to csv")
```

After You get the dataframe df

```
val resultDF = df.withColumn("split", split($"Marks", ";"))
  .withColumn("a", $"split"(0))
  .withColumn("b", $"split"(1))
  .withColumn("c", $"split"(2))
  .withColumn("d", $"split"(3))
  .groupBy("Student")
  .agg(concat_ws(";", array(
     Seq(sum($"a"), sum($"b"), sum($"c"), sum($"d")): _*)
  ).as("Marks"))


resultDF.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------------------+
|Student|Marks              |
+-------+-------------------+
|B      |60.0;60.0;60.0;40.0|
|A      |30.0;40.0;40.0;30.0|
+-------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Three Ideas. The first one is to read the file, split it by space and then create the dataFrame:

```
val df = sqlContext.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("delimiter", " ")
  .load("your_file.csv")
```

The second one is to read the file to dataframe and split it:

```
df.withColumn("Student", split($"Students Marks"," ").getItem(0))
  .withColumn("Marks", split($"Students Marks"," ").getItem(1))
  .drop("Students Marks")
```

The last one is your solution. It should work, but when you use the select, you don't use $"_tmp", therefore, it should work without the .drop("_tmp")

```
df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"Students Marks"," "))
  .select($"_tmp".getItem(0).as("Student"),$"_tmp".getItem(1).as("Marks"))
```

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`value`' given input columns : [Student  Marks];;

Comment: I edited my response, can you use `sep` instead `delimiter` too?

Comment: `val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", " ").option("header", "true").csv("path/to/file")` if this doen't work, can I see your error?

Comment: not an error here but on second line, it is throwing error org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'value' given input columns : [Student Marks];; .

Comment: I edited my response, and change  'value' with "Students Marks", try one of the three new options

Comment: while reading. it is taking them as same value. Also do you know how to add marks for a particular student

Comment: Like this? `.withColumn("Marks", if (split(col("Students Marks")," ").getItem(0) == lit("A")) split(col("Students Marks")," ").getItem(1)
        else lit("100;100;100;100"))`

Comment: df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"Students Marks"," "))
  .select($"_tmp".getItem(0).as("Student"),$"_tmp".getItem(1).as("Marks")) - it worked. Thanks. Now let me see how to add those numbers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194096/discussion-between-sahil-and-pablo-lopez-gallego).